# How do I change the keyboard shortcut to paste from clipboard in ConEMU console?

Tags: conemu

Is it possible? I couldn't find any way to customize already assigned shortcuts.

I want to change the shortcut from **Shift+Ins** to **Ctrl+V** for pasting all the text, not just the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you tried to find the way?

[image: ConEmu: Paste clipboard contents]